# Which By element can be used through selenium to identify this tag?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I would like to which `By` *xpath* or *css* to be used for the below tag:

```
<div class="title HamMenuItem__Title-kxnncH gMjAMA">Pay &amp; transfer</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this xPath:

```
//div[contains(., 'Pay') and contains(., 'transfer')]
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared you can use either of the solutions:

- *CSS-SELECTOR* using the static (partial) *class* attributes as follows:

  ```
  div.title[class*='HamMenuItem__Title-']
  ```
- *XPATH* using both the attributes *class* and *innerHTML* as follows:

  ```
  //div[contains(@class, 'title') and contains(@class, 'HamMenuItem__Title-')][contains(., 'Pay') and contains(., 'transfer')]
  ```